# Deleting iptables rule is erroring with illegal operation

Tags: iptables, centos6

I'm new to iptables but I'm trying to remove a rule based on posts I've seen online using the following command:

```
# /sbin/iptables -D INPUT 1 --protocol tcp --dport 5672 -j ACCEPT
```

But it's throwing an error:

```
iptables v1.4.7: Illegal option `-p' with this command
```

Using **CentOS 6**. Which part am I getting wrong in the syntax? I can't even see the `-p` option it's talking about unless I'm going blind - I assume it means the `--protocol` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove a rule *either* by its number in the order in which it currently appears in the running firewall rules, *or* by specifying that rule's parameters exactly. Your command line seems to be trying to do both, which is not going to work. Choose one or the other.

To remove a rule by number:

```
iptables -D INPUT 1
```

To remove a rule by specification:

```
iptables -D INPUT --protocol tcp --dport 5672 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks :) that was it!